# activity.java files with same errors -> error: cannot find symbol class Bind

Tags: java, android

import butterknife.Bindview;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class BookingSearchResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public final static String BOOKING_SEARCH_RESULT_SERIALIZED_KEY =
```

"booking_search_result_serialized";

```
@Bind(R.id.vehicle_list)//**error comes from this line cannot find symbol class Bind**
protected ListView vehicleListView;
```

---

What do i have to do or what i am missing ? New to android app development. This is a carRent app that uses google API. I have the same errors in all my activity.java files. I dont know maybe something have to do with butterknife. I also updated my android studio.

---

Comment: See [ask]. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show your [mcve] and tell us what results you got by showing any errors or stacktraces. Format the code and output so it is clear what is explanation and what is content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of **ButterKnife** library, use `@BindView` instead of `@bind`

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you this solve the problem :) Appreciate your help.